# How to change alignment of popover from v-date-picker component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using the v-calendar plugin to create a datepicker on the frontend. How can i change the position/alignment of the popover of the v-date-picker component? (While keeping all other elements centered aswell, and while only using CDN imports)

I am trying to build a frontend using Vue.js, v-calendar, Bootstrap (and Chart.js for some graphs). All these libraries/frameworks/plugins were imported into the project by using CDN links for now. I tried using the **popoverAlign** property, which was mentioned on the [v-calendar GitHub page](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar). It may be important to add, that i am using `text-align: center;` on the body to center all the elements on the page, but it seems like the popover does not get centered aswell.

This is the code i tried using:

```
Vue.use(VCalendar, {
   popoverAlign: "bottom",
})
```

But i received the errror message `Uncaught ReferenceError: VCalendar is not defined`, which was maybe caused because i use the libraries only through CDN links and did not install them otherwise.

I expected the popover to appear right under the input element of the datepicker. It actually appeared under it, but shifted to the left. 
Like this:
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddS0e.jpg)

I also tried recreating the issue in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLjt14zq/), but the problem did not appear there. I am clueless, as i don't know what is causing this weird alignment of the popover.

Comment: According to documentation, default [`datePicker.popover.placement`](https://vcalendar.io/api/defaults.html#datepicker-popover-placement) value is `bottom`. Perhaps you should explain in clear what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center align the popover on your input all you need is `popover-align="center"` on the `<v-date-picker>` element:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

const vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    selectedDate: {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@0.9.7/lib/v-calendar.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>
        Example
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      Other stuff here
    </div>
    <div>
      <v-date-picker :max-date='new Date()' 
                     mode='range' 
                     v-model="selectedDate" 
                     popover-align="center">
      </v-date-picker>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked now! Is it possible to add any of the properties (mentioned on the v-calendar plugin GitHub) just by adding an attribute to the HTML component?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure they're in the correct format. In here it worked because `popover-align` takes a string as parameter. But if the param is something else (a number or an object), you might have to pass it as JavaScript expression. In the above case the JS expression format would have been: `:popover-align="'center'"`. Note the colon before the attribute name ( = parse as JS expression) and the single quotes inside the double quotes (= parse as string). Because default HTML attribute type is string, I ditched both.